# Take an `Iterator` instead of `Vec` when possible?

Tags: arrays, vector, iterator, rust

When a function takes a series of values as a parameter, is it considered good style to accept an `Iterator<T>` instead of `Vec<T>`?

This way, the caller can decide on their own how the series is stored (inside a `Vec`, a `[T; N]` or anything else, actually an `Option<T>` should be possible!). Also, this eliminates the need to convert the whatever you have into a `Vec`, and also, after applying some Iterator modifiers, no `.collect()` is needed! So it should also be faster!

Am I missing something or is this the way it should be done?

Answer (score 12):

Such a function as you describe should typically generically take an [`IntoIterator<Item = T>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html); thus it can accept both `Iterator<T>` and `Vec<T>` as input.

This can be combined with other techniques, too; for example, this method `concat` will accept a `&[&str]` (and thus `&Vec<&str>` by auto deref/ref coercion), `&[String]` (and thus `&Vec<String>`), a `&str` iterator, a `String` iterator, *et cetera*:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn concat<T: Borrow<str>, Iter: IntoIterator<Item = T>>(iter: Iter) -> String {
    iter.into_iter()  // -> impl Iterator<Item = T>
        .map(|s| s.borrow()) // -> impl Iterator<Item = &str>
        .collect()  // -> String
}
```

(This specific example would actually typically be better suited to [`Concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/slice/trait.Concat.html), because it’s able to calculate how long the final result will be up front and thus allocate the right length string all at once. But it’s just a proof of the concept and how multiple fancy techniques can be combined.)